# Is there any way to access the Aura $A global instance namespace or AuraLocalizationService through a VisualForce page?

Tags: visualforce, aura, attribute, localization

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
$A.localizationService.WallTimeToUTC(d, timezone, function(utc) {
    displayDate = $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(utc, format, langLocale);
})
```

from a VisualForce page. I would like to be able to access the aura lightning $A global instance namespace from the VisualForce page, use components like `<ui:outputCurrency>`, or at least the localization service. If possible, what is the easiest workaround/way to accomplish this?

Comment: By using lightning out and converting you VF page to a lightning component. It's the only way $A is accessible AFAIK. You could always use JS localization methods I believe

Comment: I would if I could, but I can't. Might have to use JS library. Any best suggestions for SF? I have looked at a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make an empty lightning app and component and call your `localizationservice` function in the callback of that component creation.

Something like this:

```
<apex:page >

    <!--rest of your page stuff -->

    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div style="display: none !important; id="lightning" />
    <script>
    var displayDate;

    $Lightning.use("c:EmptyApp", function () {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:EmptyComponent", {},
         lightning, function (cmp) {
             $A.localizationService.WallTimeToUTC(d, timezone, function(utc) {
                 displayDate = $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(utc, format, langLocale);
                     console.log(displayDate);
             })
         });
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

You could even try saving a reference to `$A` so you can call it again without instantiating a dummy component - ie in the callback, do something like:

```
window.$A = $A;
```

I don't know if this will work, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Works. Probably can't do any better workaround...

Comment: It's a bit naughty, but I'm glad it works.